# How to get Python packages installed as .exe to run on Windows 10; "failed to create process"

Tags: python, pip, cpplint

After installing Python 3.5.1 on Windows 10 x64, `cpplint` installed from `pip` produces the error: `failed to create process`.  There seems to be a possibly related issue with `pip` related to having a space in the path, which exists in my use case.  It seems to be related to how the exe is created.  How can this error be remedied?  Reinstalling Python and `cpplint` does not solve the problem.

```
C:\Users>python -V
Python 3.5.1

C:\Users>pip list
pip (7.1.2)
setuptools (18.2)

C:\Users>pip -V
pip 7.1.2 from c:\users\john hagen\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)

C:\Users>pip install cpplint
Collecting cpplint
  Using cached cpplint-0.0.6.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: cpplint
  Running setup.py install for cpplint
Successfully installed cpplint-0.0.6

C:\Users>where.exe cpplint
C:\Users\John Hagen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\cpplint.exe

C:\Users>cpplint
failed to create process.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is a [pip bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2783).

The workaround is to add quotes around the path in the first line of generated python scripts in the \Scripts\ directory. In the case of cpplint this is 'cpplint-script.py'. In your case the generated first line should something like:

```
#!c:\users\john hagen\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe
```

and should be edited to:

```
#!"c:\users\john hagen\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe"
```